# Download images from URL to array of images, and then display each image after each other

Tags: ios, swift

So this is what I am trying to do:

> 1. Query from `Parse.com` (`PFFile` to array - strings stored in array as .png link)
> 2. Download the images from array using [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) to a array of images
> 3. Set the first image to a `UIImageView`.
> 4. When tapping the `UIImageView`, I want to change to the next image.

**The problem is that the image doesn't show up until i tap the `UIImageView`, and when I tap to try change the image, the same UIImage is showing all the time.**

This is what my ViewController code looks like:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var userFile = [PFFile]()
    var createdAt = [NSDate]()
    var objID = [String]()

    var countInt = 0

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    var imageArray: [UIImageView] = []
    let imageToArray = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageToArray.frame.size = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)

        queryStory()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func downloadImages() {
        if (countInt <= userFile.count - 1){
            imageToArray.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: userFile[countInt].url!)!)
            countInt = countInt + 1
            imageArray.insert(imageToArray, atIndex: 0)
            print("Image downloaded. Current count: \(imageArray.count)")
            self.downloadImages()
        }
        else{
            print("no more items")
            countInt = 0
            setImage()
        }

    }

    func setImage() {
        imageView.image = imageArray[0].image
        countInt = countInt + 1
        print("setImage set")
    }

    func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
    {
        print("tapped")

        if (countInt <= imageArray.count - 1){
            imageView.image = nil
            print("set new image")
            imageView.image = imageArray[countInt].image
            countInt = countInt + 1
        }
        else{
            print("no more items")
        }
    }

    func queryStory(){

        let query = PFQuery(className: "myClass")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                // Success fetching objects

                print("Post count:", posts!.count)

                for post in posts! {

                    if let imagefile = post["userFile"] as? PFFile {
                        self.userFile.append(post["userFile"] as! PFFile)
                        self.objID.append(post.objectId!)
                        self.createdAt.append(post.createdAt!)
                    }
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    print("Done")
                    self.downloadImages()
                }

                print("Uploaded files count: ", self.userFile.count)
            }
            else{
                print(error)

                let alert = UIAlertView()
                alert.title = "Error"
                alert.message = error?.localizedDescription
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alert.show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have been messing around trying to fix this for many many hours now - but i can't figure out whats wrong.. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try removing imageView.image = nil